# How can I defer a callback with no arguments in Iced Coffeescript? (Blocking call)

Tags: coffeescript, iced-coffeescript

For example:

```
await Meteor.call "putCampaign", url, daily_budget, defer campaign_id
```

is a callback with a callback with a single argument.

How can I defer a call without a single argument?

In code, instead of:

```
callback(campaign_id)
```

The blocking call calls

```
callback()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defer is a function that takes the place of the callback, so you simply would use defer()

```js
await Meteor.call "putCampaign", url, daily_budget, defer()
```